# DIfferent Font in Text Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

i created one form in html and i wrote CSS to text fields. I set font family ARIAL to text boxes. Now i need to set Arabic Font as default particular text boxes. Not in all text boxes.

i used the following code

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Traditional Arabic';
    src: url('trado.ttf');
    src: local('trado Regular'), local('trado'), url('trado.ttf') format('truetype');
}
input[type=text].firstnamearabic, input[type=text].secondnamearabic, input[type=text].familynamearabic {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-family:"Traditional Arabic" !important;
}
```

But, when i will typing, default english letters only coming. Arabic letters are not coming.

I am seeing different font style in that particular text boxes. But it not coming in ARABIC Caption.

Comment: This might sound a bit silly but I assume you need to use some sort of IME to type Arabic. So if you type some in notepad you need to switch IME from English to Arabic. Did you switch when typing in that box.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the following in there? ودي

Comment: This is online ticket booking Form. Client need to type names in both english and Arabic Fonts

Comment: Ok, that's great but not sure what that has to do with my comments. As other people have commented; you don't need the font as people who need to type Arabic have IME on their computer to do so. As far as your CSS is concerned it should be enough to have right to left. Setting the font does not change setting input type. One great way to get input without having the right IME installed is going to google translate, they have JS input types there.

Comment: So if you ever need to type Japanese, Chinese, Arabic ... on a public or friend's computer that doesn't have the IME for it then you can use the one on google translate without installing anything.

Answer (score 1):

the css format the output, not the input.

To write in Arabic alphabet or whatever alphabet in a webpage or whatever software you need your keyboard set for utf-8 Arabic output.

don't use fonts that convert latin alphabet; those are clumsy and not reliable
if your users type in Arabic the chances are real high (99%) that their OS is set with Arabic keyboard input & therefore the font used in css absolutely does not matter (i believe Arial is safe for use for any utf-8 alphabet input)

So basically what you need is your html & your db to be set to receive utf-8 so that whatever the user input it will be recorded as such by your app.

Although since Arabic is right to left I think, you also need to set text-direction accordingly for your input. However i do not not know how you can detect whether the user is inputing in Arabic/latin (that is if you want the flexibility to allow user any of the two)

NB: if you're inputting with your keyboard set for Arabic, then do remove the Arabic font from css, if you had, then add the text-direction correct, if you had then well sorry for not appropriate answer!

Answer (score 0):

Setting font family is not supposed to change the identity of characters or keyboard functionality. An “A” is still an A, a Latin letter, independently of font. So everything should work as it does when using Arial, just with different style for letters (Latin and Arabic). This is what seems to happen.

You can e.g. select an Arabic keyboard layout in Windows, and then the keys will produce Arabic letters – quite independently of font settings.

Normally, it is best to use the same font for texts in different languages, especially if the texts appear as comparable like here. Since Arial covers Arabic letters too, it is a good start.